# How to reduce and gradually increase the volume of specific parts of an audio with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to join 2 audios and record it in an mp3 file so that the 2 audios are played simultaneously. I already managed to do this with ffmpeg. What I could not do was the setup process and playback volume. I'll try to exemplify:

- Audio 1 is a song
- Audio 2 is a voice narrating a text;

Audio 1 should start playing alone at 100% volume for 15 seconds until its volume should be reduced gradually until it reaches approximately 10% of the volume. Then audio 2 starts playing at maximum volume. As soon as audio 2 finishes playing the volume of audio 1 that is at 10%, it should increase gradually to 100% and play for another 15 seconds and that's it. Stop.

Does anyone help me how to do this with ffmpeg?